# Parcel returning null boolean array

Tags: java, android, arrays, boolean, parcelable

I have created a parcelable object which contains a boolean array

```
public class Alarm implements Parcelable {

private int hours;
private int minutes;
private int alarmTime;
private int ID;
private boolean alarmSet;
private boolean[] days;
private String[] symbols;
private String sound;
private boolean snooze;
private String picture;

public Alarm() {
    days = new boolean[7];
    symbols = new String[]{"月","火","水","木","金","土","日","毎日"};
}

protected Alarm(Parcel in) {
    hours = in.readInt();
    minutes = in.readInt();
    alarmTime = in.readInt();
    in.readBooleanArray(days);
    ID = in.readInt();
    alarmSet = in.readByte() != 0x00;
    sound = in.readString();
    snooze = in.readByte() != 0x00;
    symbols = new String[]{"月","火","水","木","金","土","日","毎日"};
    picture = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(hours);
    dest.writeInt(minutes);
    dest.writeInt(alarmTime);
    dest.writeInt(ID);
    dest.writeBooleanArray(days);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (alarmSet ? 0x01 : 0x00));
    dest.writeString(sound);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (snooze ? 0x01 : 0x00));
    dest.writeString(picture);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Alarm> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Alarm>() {
    @Override
    public Alarm createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Alarm(in);
    }
    @Override
    public Alarm[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Alarm[size];
    }
};
```

The array isnt null before it is written but on the other end gives me a null array error when I try to do either

```
in.readBooleanArray(days);
days = createBooleanArray();
```

I think that I followed the correct method for creating a parcelable object, most of the values seem to be fine(havent checked all of them)

Here is the logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.test.alarm/com.android.test.alarm.AlarmSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readBooleanArray(Parcel.java:807)
                                                                        at com.android.test.alarm.Alarm.<init>(Alarm.java:149)
                                                                        at com.android.test.alarm.Alarm$1.createFromParcel(Alarm.java:181)
                                                                        at com.android.test.alarm.Alarm$1.createFromParcel(Alarm.java:178)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
                                                                        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:755)
                                                                        at com.android.test.alarm.AlarmSettings.onCreate(AlarmSettings.java:19)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I added the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it `null`. Look at your `read`, `write`:

```
// your Alarm(Parcel in)
hours = in.readInt();
minutes = in.readInt();
alarmTime = in.readInt();
in.readBooleanArray(days);
// Your write function:
 dest.writeInt(hours);
dest.writeInt(minutes);
dest.writeInt(alarmTime);
dest.writeInt(ID);
dest.writeBooleanArray(days);
```

As above functions, you write the `BooleanArrays` in 5th value, but you read it as 4th value --> of course it is null. Hence you should change the write position or read position.

Comment: yes, its working now. I didnt know about the importance of the ordering. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have not initiated your array. Add `this()` to the second constructor

```
protected Alarm(Parcel in) {
    this();//add this to make sure arrays are initialised
    dest.writeInt(hours);
    dest.writeInt(minutes);
```

Comment: You need to read from the Parcel in the same order in which you wrote things. I see `ID` and `Day` are swapped